# How do I obtain values of a curve f(x1,x2) = 0 in R to visualize it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have `ggplot` scatters of points and I'm trying to visualize the different decision boundaries i get with `glm`. I can grab the coefficients from `glm` and I end up with something like `f(x1,x2) = 0` which could have power interactions so I can't just try `abline`. What's the simplest way to visualize it on the scatter? I was thinking if there's a "solver" maybe which will return a frame of points on a grid that I can then `geom_line` maybe?

Comment: If you are using generalized linear models why would you not use `predict` ?

Comment: What I'm trying to plot alongside the 2D point scatter is the decision boundary of the logit.

Comment: This is a bit abstract to answer generally, it would help if you made it more specific by adding a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way solutions can be tested and verified.